# What is the best way to check performance for table vs view?

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

Could you please advice what is the best solution for compare performance of query for Table vs View.

I mean have have two databases on same server (`SQL Server 2016`). Both include same data but in different schemas so for let say database `A` we have data in one table `A.Data`, on database B same data is on tables `B.Data1`, `B.Data2` and `B.Data3`. So on database `B` there are some VIEVs which are showing same data as table Data on database `A` (so for above example let say we have view `View_Data` on database `B`).

What is the best way to compare performance/efficiency for queries for table `A.Data` and view `B.View_Data` ? Just `SET STATICTICS IO ON` and compare these statistics ?

Comment: Side note: if the view is less performant (which it probably won't be considering it's probably reading less actual data), you could consider an indexed view. This means you can maintain proper normalization, while still getting the performance benefits of a single table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET STATISTICS ON` can give you a quick hint, but logical and physical reads isn't everything. Also, the output can be cumbersome to compile considering you can have several iterations, several tables and different types of physical IO. The statistics parser can be helpful: http://statisticsparser.com/.

I tend to fire up an Extended Event (XE) trace and in there compare the duration, CPU etc. To me that is a more complete picture and also easier to digest. Some find XE difficult to work with, but I literally fire up such a trace in just a few seconds. Here's a blog post I wrote on using XE and avoid some hurdles etc: http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/tips-for-getting-started-with-extended-events/